# What video file format and codec uses the least processing power?

Tags: video, format, resolution, codec

I just would like to know what format and codec would use the least processing power when the file is being played back, but still maintain a good quality, in my specific case it needs to have at least a 720p resolution. Don't worry about the file size, it can be as big as it needs to be. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everyone knows that you can get least processing power with NO COMPRESSION at all.  But then, you will kill your storage device, bus and/or network.

Try to provide some constraints to the question...

EDIT:

Each pixel is at least 2 bytes (YUY2 format for example).  Calculate your data-rate for video:

```
width * height * 2 * frames_per_second
```

and estimate if your device can handle such throughput.

Also with uncompressed video, you'll get MAXIMUM quality there is.

Further reading:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_codecs

FURTHER EDIT:

Since some aren't happy with the answer, try to answer this:  What data compression method uses LEAST CPU power.

Answer is the same: STORE.

It would be better if op was to add some constraints, for example, "what video compression uses least CPU on decompression while handling FULL PAL video frames at 25fps on about 1mbit?"

In addition to that, op should provide info on what he did try, what results were obtained, etc.

Comment: Well, I'm looking for codecs, implying that no compression at all is not an option. Simply out of all those available which one uses the least processing power? Or which one compresses the least?

Comment: Did you check out the wiki I added to the answer?

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question at all

Comment: @DanielMošmondor That doesn't really add anything. You haven't even tried to discuss a few codecs, and linking to a Wikipedia page doesn't constitute an answer. Also, although admittedly the OP isn't the most detailed the author did already specify 720p from the beginning and that his question is about processing requirements for playback.

Comment: @Michael how much do you actually know of video formats, pixel packing in bitmaps etc. so you can make that claim.  LEAST amount of CPU is copying bitmap directly to the screen. PERIOD.  I won't run benchmarks for him, that's for sure.